# Override a css class in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` (page between menu stuff) inside a `div` (some random buttons) next to another `div` (`div` next to random buttons) I want to center text in the last div. Both  and style=text-align didn't work as well as adding a new class, the last thing I tried was using a span to center it

```
<span style="text-align:center"><?php echo $tUser."'s profile";?></span>
```

It doesn't center in the div which has `maxwidth:500px` (so the text should center at 250px), it just stays where it was.

All divs have their own classes, and I can't seem to override the text to center it within the last div.

http://prntscr.com/3fhwuy

That's the third div

```
<div style="maxwidth:500px;" class="userprofile">
                <?php if($_SESSION['profilepage']=="vievprofile"){// VIEV PROFILE
                addPointer($pointer,174,145);?>
                <p style="margin: 0 auto"><?php echo $tUser."'s profile";?></span>

 </div>
```

None of the classes has a `float:left;`.

" Make up your mind, is it a p or a span? –  jeroen 1 min ago "
It's a stone. Actually, whatever works.

Fixed with position:absolute, not the best fix though.

Comment: It's difficult to trace what you're facing. can you create a fiddle?

Comment: You need to post your complete html and css regarding that section. As it is not it does not make sense, a `span` is an inline element so centering in it does nothing and `maxwidth` does not necessarily set the with of the box.

Comment: By the way, I removed the php tag as that is irrelevant to the question / problem.

Comment: Can you show us the class definition for div3?

Comment: Usually if the parent has `float:left` (unless overriden to another child), the child will inherit that and even if you use `text-align: center` the child's `float` will override it. So to give you a correct answer we need the exact html and css to be seen. You can update your question or post to jsfiddle and point to that link

Comment: Make up your mind, is it a `p` or a `span`?

Comment: You do realize the code you originally posted is different from the code you posted in your edit, right? Opening `p`, closing `span`, different css...

Comment: fiddle.net , insert the code and put the link here

Answer (score 2):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nfyPK/1/)

Here you go :)

```
<div style="max-width:500px;" class="userprofile">
        <p style="text-align:center;">Hello</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yep, thats it.. @user3569990

Comment: Didn't work, apparently I have to completely rewrite this script since no one can find the error.

Comment: @user3569990 You need to post the real generated html and the css.

Comment: @user3569990 if this didn't work therefore you are overwriting some style somewhere else, because the link prove that the code works.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E96Ln/2/).
New [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E96Ln/5/) **without** *absolute positioning*.

The following line is valid for html *'block'* elements. Don't use this on *'inline'* elements like a 'span'.

```
<p style="text-align: center">User profile</p>
```

**Important Note:** Use the correct css-property **max-width** instead of **maxwidth**

Hope this helps so far.

Comment: I have not downvoted yet, but this will only center a block element inside its parent if its width is less that the parent's width. Of which I don't see any indication in the question nor in your anwser.

Comment: @Amir Thanks for the downvote. Now I'm not able to ask questions anymore

Comment: @pbaldauf I didn't, but here you go. Note that `style="text-align: center"` does not make sense on a `span` / an inline element.

Comment: That's true but I am referring that line to the div in the fiddle

Comment: You might as well get rid of the max-width and margin as the only effect it will have, is to wrap the contents. The centering is already done.